# moving a function to java script

Tags: javascript, user-defined-functions

I need to pull the function out of the following html document, create a separate js document that will contain the function and modify my existing code so that it includes my js file.  Then I must create a new function in my html file called "DoTheLink."  I will call that function from the function in my js file.  "DoTheLink" will be passed the website variable and will set the onclick attribute for the button.

Here is what I have to work with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>funky jumper </title>
</head>

<body>
<script>


var surfCaption="You\'ve selected: Bird Rock Surf Cam";
var surfButton="Bird Rock Surf Cam";
var surfWeb="http://www.surfline.com/surf-report/birdrock-7-california_4249";
var grandmaCaption="You\'ve selected: Grandma\'s Weather";
var grandmaButton="Grandma\'s Weather";
var grandmaWeb="http://www.weather.com/weather/today/Bronx+NY+10463:4:US";
var dollCaption="You\'ve selected: Noodle-head sewing";
var dollButton="Noodle-head sewing";
var dollWeb="http://www.noodle-head.com/2010/01/another-round-of-black-apple-dolls.html";

</script>
<div style="text-align: center">

<table align="center">
<td> <img src="http://nees.oregonstate.edu/killer_wave/wave.jpg" alt="Surf" border="3" height="280" width="172" onclick="uno(surfCaption, surfButton, surfWeb);">
</td>
<td> <img src="http://wirednewyork.com/images/city-guide/liberty/liberty.jpg"  alt="Grandma's Weather" border="3" height=280  width=200
onclick="uno(grandmaCaption, grandmaButton, grandmaWeb);">
</td>
<td> <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/__A1V8kztPXs/S1XYcpBScbI/AAAAAAAAA00/S_nd0bNtUR8/s640/helpfulhannahpresent3.jpg" alt="Noodle-head" border="3" height=280  width=180
onclick="uno(dollCaption, dollButton, dollWeb);">
</td>
</table>

<p id="captionUnderTable" >Nothing Selected</p>
<br>
<button id="NewButton" >Click on a picture, then click me to go!</button>
</div>

<script>
 function uno(Caption, Button, Web)
{
document.getElementById("captionUnderTable").innerHTML=Caption;
document.getElementById("NewButton").innerHTML=Button;
document.getElementById("NewButton").setAttribute('onclick','window.location.href="'+Web+'";')
<!--When the picture is clicked, go get the variable associated with that picture-->
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to put what is between the < script > tags in another file, this link might help: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470901/So-You-Want-An-External-JavaScript-Huh.htm